# Why calling address-of operator on rvalues compiles?

Tags: c++, iterator, addressof

AFAIK it is illegal to take the address of an rvalue because the address-of operator `&` takes an lvalue and returns the address of the object's called on address.

Here is an example I've tried to understand but find it a bit confusing:

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    using std::endl;

    std::deque<int> di{ 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13 };

    std::deque<int>::iterator it = di.end() - 1; 

    cout << *it << endl;
    cout << &it-- << endl; // is it UB?
    cout << *it << endl;
    cout << &it-- << endl;
    cout << *it << endl;
    cout << &it-- << endl;
    cout << *it << endl << endl;

    cout << &--it << endl; // ok
    cout << *it << endl; // ok
    cout << &--it << endl; // ok
    cout << *it << endl; // ok



    std::cout << std::endl << "done!" << std::endl;
}
```

- In the lines where I've used the pre-decrement operator it is OK because this operator and `&` have the same precedence level and are evaluated from right-to-left (RL) thus `--` evaluates first and it returns an lvalue (takes also lvalue). then `&` is evaluated so `&` on an lvalue is OK.
- The problem above in the post-decrement operator which takes an lvalue and returns an rvalue and has higher precedence over `&`. So in these expressions I am calling `&` on rvalue which is normally not allowed. But why the code compile and gives different results (addresses)??
- When compiled on Wandbox with flag `-pedantic` it doesn't compile:

  ```
  prog.cc:25:17: error: taking address of rvalue [-fpermissive]
     25 |  cout << &offEnd-- << endl; // -- has higher precedence than & thus this expression decrements offEnd and returns a copy of original of offEnd then print the address of this original object (before decrementing it)
  ```

  Also on MSVC++14 with `/Wall`.
- So is it undefined behavior in my code?
- so why C++ allowed calling address of operator `&` on rvalue while the standard disallows it?
- Finally I want to know where theses different addresses come from in such expression: `std::cout << &it-- << std::endl;`? But the values of de-referencing are correct!

Comment: *"why C++ allowed calling address of operator & on r-value while the standard disallows it?"* - I don't understand this - there is no distinction between C++ and the standard, it's simply not allowed. Did you mean to ask why the compiler allows this?

Comment: @StoryTeller:  Yes I meant it.

Comment: @UnholySheep; Yes I meant the compiler. So the different addresses come from U.B?

Comment: This is not undefined behavior: the defined behavior is a compiler error since this is not allowed in standard. You might need to dig into the generated assembly to see what your compiler is doing in this case

Comment: The correct term is "ill-formed".

Comment: @arithma: Did you mean 'the Undefined Behavior is compiler error.."?

Comment: @arithma It appears that the value category of `r--` is unspecified, where `r` is an iterator, per [Table 98](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/bidirectional.iterators#tab:iterator.bidirectional.requirements).

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings). Some compilers have extensions turned on by default, and without warnings on you never know.